# Replacing multiples of 10 in a dataset

Tags: r

I have a problem which has proven pretty hard to solve. I have a dataset `D` were I want to replace all data points that can be written as y=x*10^n where x is an integer which is not larger than 10 (e.g. y=20,300,... but not 25, 375...). I want to replace these data points y with y-1. So for example I want 20 to become 19, 300 to become 299 etc.

For example say my dataset `D` is:

```
D <- c(20, 32, 200, 300.12, 40, 213, 60, 75)
```

Then I want my new dataset to be

```
Dnew
[1]  19  32 199 300.12 39 213 59 75
```

I have tried many ways using the `gsub()` function but I can't make it work.

Comment: ` D - (D %% 10 == 0)`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Yep this works I can't believe it was so simple (clever nonetheless). It seems I have to get back to basics...